# How To Bind Dynamic Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

Can you please guide me, how to bind dynamic model when received from Swagger with this JSON data:

```
{
"RequestItems":[
    {
    "eventDate":"2023-02-27",
    "eventName":"string Update",
    "eventType":1601,
    "address":{
        "address":"address Updare",
        "note":"addressNote"
        }
    }
]
}
```

**And here my request file  And End Point :**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestItemAsync([FromRoute] Guid Id, [FromBody] UpdateRequestItems request)
{
    // line of code
}
```

```cs
public class UpdateRequestItems
{   
    public List<RequestItem> RequestItems { get; set; }
}

public class RequestItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateOnly EventDate { get; set; }    
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}

public class RequestAddress : RequestItem
{
    public TripItineraryAddress? Address { get; set; }
}

public class RequestVendor : RequestItem
{
    public TripItineraryVendor? Vendor { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDescription : RequestItem
{
    public TripItineraryDescription? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Try some custom model binder but not accept child data.

Comment: What's your API tool ? How you pass JSON data ? And  is your End Point  in an asp.net core mvc project?

Comment: Using Swagger , post Method  And  End point is asp.net core

Comment: Could you share your EventType model?

Comment: EventType is a Enum :
 public enum EventType
    {
        Address = 1601,
        Vendor = 1602,
        Description = 1603
    }

Comment: Can you explain what do you want exactly?

Comment: @fatih , i want send single request data at a time  with Address or Vendor or Description

Comment: You can create dynamic models with "ExpandoObject". You can look from there "https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0"

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify you model like:

RequestItem:

```
public class RequestItem
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateOnly EventDate { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public int EventType { get; set; }
        public Adress adress { get; set; }  
    }
```

Adress:

```
 public class Adress
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: @Amresh Is my answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: no , i have done this approach already. which are working .